# Does putting a limit to the size of a string attribute in Rails make the database smaller?

Tags: mysql, sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, postgresql

If I am using mySQL or Postgresql does putting a limit on the attribute shrink the size of the database? I guess this may be a silly question, but I am a little unfamiliar with how database size adds up.

What are some other point of emphasis when limiting the size of an SQL database with a Rails app?

Comment: Rails will use `varchar(limit)` rather than `char(limit)` and `:limit => 255` is the default. AFAIK `varchar(n)` takes up however many bytes are needed for the string and the `n` is simply a maximum length. I don't have references to back all this up so just a comment for now, someone else is welcome to dig up the necessary references in the mean time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess that is the [quote from the manual](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/datatype-character.html) [@mu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16246418/does-putting-a-limit-to-the-size-of-a-string-attribute-in-rails-make-the-databas#comment23246750_16246418) was looking for:

> The storage requirement for a short string (up to 126 bytes) is **1 byte
>   plus the actual string**, which includes the space padding in the case
>   of character. Longer strings have **4 bytes** of overhead instead of 1.
>   Long strings are compressed by the system automatically, so the
>   physical requirement on disk might be less. Very long values are also
>   stored in background tables so that they do not interfere with rapid
>   access to shorter column values.

Bold emphasis mine.

The **length specifier has no effect whatsoever** on the storage size of `text` or `varchar` types. And there is hardly any reason to use `char(n)` at all, where `n` would have an impact on storage size.

Comment: I'd go so far as to say that `char(n)` is awful and should just not be used. `varchar(n)` is OK, but it's often better to instead write a `CHECK` constraint that enforces minimum and maximum lengths.